# LINUX unable to create a directory | mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test_nfs’: Permission denied

Tags: nfs, mkdir

I am trying to create a new directory under `/mnt` but unable to do so.

I have presented a volume through nfs server to client.

```
-->RPCbind is active.

/mnt$ service rpcbind status
● rpcbind.service - RPC bind portmap service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service; enabled; vendor pres>
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-05-05 03:00:42 PDT; 40min ago
TriggeredBy: ● rpcbind.socket
       Docs: man:rpcbind(8)
   Main PID: 712 (rpcbind)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4614)
     Memory: 2.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/rpcbind.service
             └─712 /sbin/rpcbind -f -w

ubuntu:/mnt$ mkdir test_nfs
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test_nfs’: Permission denied

drwxr-xr-x   3 root root      4096 Apr 16 04:19 mnt
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`/mnt` is owned by root and has permissions only for root to create files or directories there. You cannot create `test_nfs` as an ordinary user because you do not have the permissions to do so. This is the cause of the error `Permission denied`.

Either relax the permissions on `/mnt` or create the directory as root. (Note that unless you have overridden default NFS permission settings you may still find that you cannot create the directory as root. In this case look up the `no_root_squash` option, but in a multiuser environment take great care to consider the security implications of setting it.)

Comment: Thanks it worked.
@ubuntu:/$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for xxxxx: 
root@ubuntu:/# ls
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  swapfile  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@ubuntu:/# cd /mnt
root@ubuntu:/mnt# mkdir test_nfs

Comment: @Harshita if it worked please remember to ✔ accept this answer

Answer (score -1):

Issue resolved.

```
ubuntu:/$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for xxx: 
root@ubuntu:/# ls
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  swapfile  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@ubuntu:/# cd /mnt
root@ubuntu:/mnt# mkdir test_nfs
```